# how to define twitter callback_url for android?

Tags: android, twitter

i'm trying to connect twitter for android. so I have downloaded the source from github. but i got a message, which is

```
<error>Desktop applications only support the oauth_callback value 'oob'</error>
```

but i already have defined it. 'public static final String REST_CALLBACK_URL = "hywtest://hywtwitter";'

i change callback_url to 'oob', i can come close to twitter, but when change a page, show pin number, and there's nothing happens.

of course, i have changed manifest too.

```
<data
                    android:host="hywtwitter"
                    android:scheme="hywtest" />
```

please help me!

Comment: is your problem resolved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to provide a callback URL in your Twitter Application Page in Application Details where twitter return after successful authentication.

Comment: as your comment, i change my callback url, but this is my source, and i Log it, url.startsWith(BasicInfo.TWIT_CALLBACK_URL) -> this value = false. so i can't get oauthToken and oauthVerifier. for reference, my callback url is "www.naver.com"

Comment: follow this link http://www.androidhive.info/2012/09/android-twitter-oauth-connect-tutorial/ @jungeum

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide a placeholder callback URL on your application record on dev.twitter.com -- this placeholder allows you to perform callback-based auth with a dynamically supplied callback on the oauth/request_token step.